# Replace Data with Second Row keep first row as it is

Tags: java, etl

I am trying to replace projected stock value into inventory column but it is replacing all values of inventory.I want to keep first line as it is from second line projected stock value that is -300 should go to inventory column.

```
date           Inventory    Demand      Projected Stock 

7/1/2013        200          500            -300

7/2/2013                     100

7/3/2013                 ``  200    

integer c=0;
integer temp=0;
integer count1;
integer i=1;            

while(c==0){


        Inventory == null
        {
            $out.0.Inventory=0;
        }
        c++;
        Projected_Stock = Inventory-Demand;
        temp=Projected_Stock;
    }



    for(integer i=2;i<=count1;i++)
{
        Projected_Stock = temp - Demand;
        temp=Projected_Stock;
        Inventory=temp;
    }
    i++;
```

Comment: This is not valid Java code. Could you double-check? Is this code embedded somewhere? If so, what is the name of the tool?

Comment: Right This code is embedded in Clover ETL Tool.Thanks Problem is resoloved..:)

Comment: If the problem is resolved I would suggest that you either delete the question or provide an answer yourself.